# Meta tag in nuxt 2 not showing in messenger and instagram chat

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxtjs2

i have problem using nuxt 2 in metadata, i try share my website link but metadata not showing. this problem come only in messenger and instagram and work good in other platform.

[link in instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMuS7.png) [link on whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhxCr.jpg) [this my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM6jr.jpg)

please someone help me, i already stuck in this case 1 week.
thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask